# Create an obstacles inside the map

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

i already create a map like this:

[image]

Now i want to draw a obstacles within those grids, how do i do that?

Right now i only be able to draw a obstacles during mouse down, but i am not able to generate a map that have a obstacles once i run the game.

Please help me.

Here is my code for making a grid in unity3d (c#):

```
public GameObject TilePrefab;
public List<List<Tile>> map = new List<List<Tile>>();
public int mapSize = 20; 

void GenerateMap() 
    {
        map = new List<List<Tile>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < mapSize; i++) 
        {
         List <Tile> row = new List<Tile>();

            for (int j = 0; j < mapSize; j++)
            {
                Tile tile = ((GameObject)Instantiate(TilePrefab, new Vector3(i - Mathf.Floor(mapSize / 2), 0, -j + Mathf.Floor(mapSize / 2)), Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3()))).GetComponent<Tile>();
          tile.gridPosition = new Vector2(i, j);
          row.Add(tile);
         }

            map.Add(row);
       }
    }
```

And here is my code for draw a obstacles once i hit the mouse button (OnMouseDown):

```
public bool obstacles = false;
void OnMouseDown()
    {
        obstacles = obstacles ? false : true;

        if (obstacles)
        {
            transform.renderer.material.color = new Color(.5f, .5f, 0.0f);
        }

        else
        {
            transform.renderer.material.color = Color.white;
        }
    }
```

Thank you very much! I appreciate your answer

Comment: You've got an `OnMouseDown` method there - what component is that method in? I ask because you aren't *creating* an obstacle as a GameObject, but you're changing the colour of something. I'm guessing some of your tiles are obstacles and are coloured to indicate this? If so, why can't you set the colour of certain tiles during the `GenerateMap` method?

Answer (score 0):

A few consideration here :

Why using List in that case as a very good way (fast) to store coordinate is either (for s = side length) :

- int[s*s] <- that one is great if you want to edit map on GPU
- int[s][s]
- int[s,s] <- that one is great for CPU operations

Arrays are fast

To generate specific tiles at startup you have different options this is pseudo code :

```
GameObject[,] tiles = new GameObject[s,s];
public GameObject[] arrayOfTilesTypes; // Simply populate this in inspector with blocking and non blocking gameObjects

for(int i = 0; i<s;  i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j<s;  j++) {
        int objtype = Random.Range(0,arrayOfTilesType.Length);
        tiles[i,j] = Instanciate(arrayOfTilesTypes[objtype],new Vector3(i,0,j),Quaternion.Identity) as GameObject;
    }
}
```

There is many other way of doing that though.
EDIT : 
Provided more straight forward solution

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the original question. You seem to have posted an array-based version of the `GenerateMap` method with no suggestion for how to create the obstacles.

Comment: Well i precised that user should put obstacle tiles and classic tiles in the arrayOfTilesTypes[] in the inspector, but that's one of many answers possibles